# What is the limit of this recursively defined function ${a}_{n}= \sqrt{12+{a}_{n-1}}$

Tags: limits

What is the limit of this recursively defined function?
$${a}_{n}= \sqrt{12+{a}_{n-1}}$$

By looking at its graph, the answer seems to be $4$; but how can it be proven that the limit exists, and how can it be calculated?

Comment: you need the first point....

Comment: Notice $a_n\in [0,\infty)$ for all $n\geq 1$ *regardless*  of how you pick $a_0\in [-12,\infty)$. Moreover, if $f(x)=\sqrt{12+x}$ then $|f'(x)|\leq \frac{1}{4\sqrt{3}}$ on $[0,\infty)$. Use MVT to see for any $n\geq 1$ that $$|a_{n+1}-4|=|f(a_n)-f(4)|\leq \frac{1}{4\sqrt{3}}|a_n-4|$$

Answer (score 2):

To prove the limit exists, note that it must be the case that $a_0 \geq -12$ in order for $a_1$ to be defined, so it must be the case that $a_1 \geq 0$ and thus $a_2 \geq \sqrt{12} > 3$. A quick induction shows that $a_i > 3$ for all $i \geq 2$.

Now consider that the map $f : [3, \infty) \to [3, \infty)$ defined by $f(x) = \sqrt{x + 12}$ is a contraction map. This follows from the fact that $f'(x) \leq \frac{1}{2}$ for all $x \in \sqrt{x + 12}$; therefore, $|f(x) - f(y)| \leq \frac{1}{2} |x - y|$.

Therefore, $f$ has a unique fixed point in $[3, \infty)$. Furthermore, any sequence of the form $y, f(y), f(f(y)), ...$ has a limit, and the limit is the fixed point of $f$.

So the limit must be the fixed point $x = \sqrt{x + 12}$. Solving for $x$ gives us $x^2 = x + 12$; $x^2 - x - 12 = 0$; $(x - 4)(x + 3) = 0$. So the fixed point of $f$ is 4, and this is also the limit of $a$ regardless of the starting point.

Comment: (+1) however this will be somehow challenging to understand without any prior knowledge on the fixed point theorem

Answer (score 1):

If we suppose that the limit exists and is equal to $\ell$. Then $$\ell = \sqrt{12+\ell}\Rightarrow \ell^2=12+\ell \Rightarrow \ell=4 \text{ or } \ell=-3.$$

As the function is always positive, the $\ell$ should be positive. Then $$\ell = 4.$$

Comment: Thanks @Abdoul Haki

Comment: @SalzEngineering: If this answer helped you, you should click on the check mark button just to the top left of the post. This marks to the website that your problem got solved.